# Nexthop has invalid gateway when doing IP forwarding and address translation

Tags: iptables, vpn, openvpn, vps, wireguard

So let's say I'm a user in PC1, I have two ubuntu servers in two countries (VPS1 and VPS2) VPS1 is a WireGuard server and VPS2 is a OpenVPN server.

I want to do something like this:

PC1 ---> VPS1 ---> VPS2 ----> Internet

I'm following [this](https://github.com/AmCrypt0/VPN-Chaining) ([translation](https://github-com.translate.goog/AmCrypt0/VPN-Chaining?_x_tr_sl=fa&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp)) tutorial.

At the end of the tutorial, There are below commands to run:

```
iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 10.7.0.0/24 ! -d 10.7.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source VPS1_IP

iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT 

iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.7.0.0/24 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.7.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.2

ip route add default via 10.8.0.2 table 120 

ip rule add from 10.7.0.0/24 table 120
```

When running `ip route add default via 10.8.0.2 table 120` , I get this error: `Nexthop has invalid gateway`

I tried this tutorial one time and it worked but I get the error above when I'm doing it now.